# Delete row - always deletes the last row as index returns -1

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Reactive Form in my Angular application and one the questions allows users to add or remove rows. Every row will have a delete button. The issue that I am facing is that when I click on the delete button on a specific item, it will remove the last row instead. I have done the breakpoint at the function and it shows that the index is -1, which I know means that the last item will be removed.

```
delete_communityList_row(id) {
  const index = this.Form.value.communityList.indexOf(id);
  this.Form.value.communityList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

When the delete button is clicked, the "id" returns the id of the row that I click on so I am not entirely show what went wrong. This the console.log output which returns an array of objects.

[image]

Comment: I think `communityList` holds objects

Comment: share your template code

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes it does return an array of objects. How can I use splice to remove objects from an array?

Comment: share your template

Comment: one approach is `const index = this.Form.value.communityList.findIndex(o => o.id === id);` .... there is much better solution is there share your template

Comment: @PranavCBalan what do you mean by template code?

Comment: from where you are calling `delete_communityList_row` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `communityList` property holds object collection and you are checking the index of an id(probably string or number) which is not present in the array as an element(it's property value of the object) so it always returns `-1`. As per [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) documentation if the start value is negative then it counts from the end like `array.length - n`(`-1` means last index).

You can get an index by checking property value using [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method which iterates over the array and returns index when the callback returns `true`.

```
const index = this.Form.value.communityList.findIndex(o => o.id === id);
```

Final code :

```
delete_communityList_row(id) {
  const index = this.Form.value.communityList.findIndex(o => o.id === id);
  if(index !== -1) this.Form.value.communityList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

---

**FYI :** If you are calling the method from the template(generated using `*ngFor`) then you can pass the `index` instead of the `id` and which would be much more simple.